# DHCP Server Dynamically Updating DNS on Other Server (Both Windows 2012 R2, No AD)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server, dns-server

We have had a single Windows Server 2012 R2 server (with no Active Directory) running DNS and DHCP for our main network for a good few months with dynamic DNS updates from DHCP working fine.

We have recently setup a secondary (DR) network (in a different DC, connected to the main DC via VPN) and I have configured another Windows Server 2012 R2 server with:

1. DNS Server configured as a secondary zone of the main DC DNS server
2. DHCP Server for the new network (both DHCP servers have the same configuration: [image: configuration])

DNS resolution and DHCP address allocation both work fine. However, the DHCP server does not update the primary DNS server when new addresses are allocated.

I've looked at the log in `c:\Windows\system32\dhcp` and the secondary DHCP doesn't seem to even be attempting DNS updates against the primary DNS server.

Can anyone help explain what is going on and how to fix it?

I'm happy to add more detail if it helps!

Comment: Does the new DHCP server have a DNS suffix for the zone in question? If not, then DNS registration won't work.

Comment: All of my DHCP scopes in both networks have the same DNS suffix and I just added the same suffix to the main network connection on the secondary server. Behaviour seems to be the same though.